Detect mouse move event when over an iframe in chrome extension
I am working on a chrome extension that would inject a script on any page and get the mouse position whenever the mouse move, now everything is working fine and getting the positions whenever the mouse moves on the document, but when the mouse moves inside an iframe, its not showing the positions
const consoleMouse = (e) => {
        const { clientX, clientY } = e;
    
        console.log(`mouse at ${clientX} and ${clientY}`)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", consoleMouse);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("mousemove", consoleMouse);
        }
    }, [consoleMouse])

I have tested some chrome extensions that are able to overlay their custom svg on top of an iframe, for example ColorZilla

I would suggest looking at the source code of ColorZilla. https://crxextractor.com/

Either add a transparent div over the iframe or declare a content script that runs inside the iframe.

@wOxxOm How can I make content script run inside the iframe? any examples?

Declare it with "all_frames":true

@wOxxOm, Yes it did work, but the script is executing twice as there are two frames, i.e. its showing two custom cursor on top of page, one for the iframe and the other for the main page

Of course. An iframe is a different page with its own instance of the content script. You can check window==top to see which one it is and adjust the visuals accordingly.
